# spring boot reconnect solace jms queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, solace, solace-mq

I am using spring boot to connect to solace queue.
I have used below tutorial to connect to the solace JMS queue.
https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-jms-solace-example
It is able to make connection to the solace queue.
We faced one issue when application is started and connection with solace queue is working fine but after some time solace queue went down then spring boot application should reconnect to solace queue instead of restarting application to connect.
To reconnect with solace queue I have added

```
 connectionFactory.setReconnectRetries(-1);
 connectionFactory.setReconnectRetryWaitInMillis(3000);
 connectionFactory.setConnectRetries(-1);
 connectionFactory.setConnectRetriesPerHost(5);
```

so code will look like below

```
   @Bean
    public SolConnectionFactory solConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        SolConnectionFactory connectionFactory = SolJmsUtility.createConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(environment.getProperty("solace.java.host"));
        connectionFactory.setVPN(environment.getProperty("solace.java.msgVpn"));
        connectionFactory.setUsername(environment.getProperty("solace.java.clientUsername"));
        connectionFactory.setPassword(environment.getProperty("solace.java.clientPassword"));
        connectionFactory.setClientID(environment.getProperty("solace.java.clientName"));
         connectionFactory.setReconnectRetries(-1);
         connectionFactory.setReconnectRetryWaitInMillis(3000);
         connectionFactory.setConnectRetries(-1);
         connectionFactory.setConnectRetriesPerHost(5);
         
        return connectionFactory;
    }



 @Bean
    public JmsMessageListener jmsMessageListener() {
        return new JmsMessageListener();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public Connection connection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        javax.jms.Session session;
        try {
            connection = solConnectionFactory().createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(environment.getProperty("solace.message.consumer.queue"));
            MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            messageConsumer.setMessageListener(jmsMessageListener());
            connection.setExceptionListener(exceptionListener);
            connection.start();
            logger.info("Connected. Awaiting message...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("JMS connection failed with Solace." + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.solacesystems</groupId>
    <artifactId>sol-jms</artifactId>
    <version>10.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.solacesystems</groupId>
    <artifactId>sol-jcsmp</artifactId>
    <version>10.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here it does not go into exception listener if solace queue connection is interupted and by adding reconnect properties also it does not show in log whether application is reconnecting to solace queue or not. How to reconnect to solace queue if solace queue is up after some time

Kindly help

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? @Coder Guru

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking your log levels. You're configuring the right thing with reconnectRetries, etc.

You should see something like below. I get those logs when running this app: https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-spring/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfig-receiver/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/spring/boot/SpringBootReceiver.java

```
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:21.742[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:21.825[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 1, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:21.851[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connected to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (smfclient 1)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:21.890[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.s.s.spring.boot.SpringBootReceiver    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started SpringBootReceiver in 3.494 seconds (JVM running for 4.445)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:24.475[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(1)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:24.475[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(1)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:24.477[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(1)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 2 ms
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:46.310[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[2_ReactorThread][0;39m [36mc.s.jcsmp.impl.flow.UnbindRequestTask   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Error Response (503) - Service Unavailable; subCode: 50; flowId=0
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:46.326[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-1][0;39m [36mo.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'SpringTestQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: Error receiving message - internal error (503: Unknown Queue)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:46.332[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-1][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Channel Closed (smfclient 1)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:46.355[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-1][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 2, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:46.370[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-1][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connected to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (smfclient 2)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:51.390[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-2][0;39m [36mo.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'SpringTestQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: Error creating consumer - unknown endpoint (503: Unknown Queue)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:51.391[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-2][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Channel Closed (smfclient 2)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:51.397[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-2][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 3, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:51.408[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-2][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connected to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (smfclient 3)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:56.426[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-3][0;39m [36mo.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'SpringTestQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: Error creating consumer - unknown endpoint (503: Unknown Queue)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:56.427[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-3][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Channel Closed (smfclient 3)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:56.434[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-3][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 4, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
[2m2021-12-01 13:45:56.441[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-3][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connected to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (smfclient 4)
[2m2021-12-01 13:46:01.454[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-4][0;39m [36mo.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'SpringTestQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: Error creating consumer - unknown endpoint (503: Unknown Queue)
[2m2021-12-01 13:46:01.455[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-4][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Channel Closed (smfclient 4)
[2m2021-12-01 13:46:01.463[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-4][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 5, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
[2m2021-12-01 13:46:01.473[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23127[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntContainer#0-4][0;39m [36mc.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connected to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:4444, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=4444' (smfclient 5)
```